# Random circles with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I didn't manage to find a jQuery plugin that permit to create random circles like this :

Can you help me please ?

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}

.circle .blue {
    background-color: #00c0f1;
}

.circle .green {
    background-color: #add036;
}

.circle .red {
    background-color: #ec2426;
}

.circle .yellow {
    background-color: #ffc116;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply create new divs programatically (for example using `$("<div />")`) and assign the width, height and position properties randomly. For example, to create one circle, I might do something like this:

```
var newCircle = $("<div />")
var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxDiam);
newCircle.addClass("circle");

newCircle.css({
    width: d,
    height: d,
    left: Math.random() * Math.max($("#container").width() - d, 0),
    top: Math.random() * Math.max($("#container").height - d, 0),
    backgroundColor: getRandomColor()
});
$("#container").append(newCircle);
```

You could either choose *truly* random colours (for example using this solution: [Random circles with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32126078/1590962)), or just choose from the colours you selected:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var colours = ["#00c0f1", "#add036", "#ec2426", "#ffc116"];
    return colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
}
```

Here is a full example putting that all together: http://jsfiddle.net/hephistocles/b63ja0h3/3/

Comment: Came here by accident, but really like your solution!